# How to convert Excel file to json using pandas?

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like to parse Excel file which has a couple of sheets and save a data in JSON file.

I don't want to parse first and second sheet, and also the last one. I want to parse those in between and that number of sheets is not always equal and names of those sheets are not always the same.

```
import pandas
import json

# Read excel document
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
```

Is there a way not to put this parameter `sheet_name`?

```
# Convert excel to string 
# (define orientation of document in this case from up to down)
thisisjson = excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records')

# Print out the result
print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', thisisjson)

# Make the string into a list to be able to input in to a JSON-file
thisisjson_dict = json.loads(thisisjson)

# Define file to write to and 'w' for write option -> json.dump() 
# defining the list to write from and file to write to
with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(thisisjson_dict, json_file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create a sheet level dict and loop through each of the sheets. Something like this:

```
import pandas
import json

sheets = ['sheet1','sheet2','sheet3']
output = dict()
# Read excel document
for sheet in sheets:
    excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet)

# Convert excel to string 
# (define orientation of document in this case from up to down)
    thisisjson = excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records')
    
# Print out the result
    print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', thisisjson)

# Make the string into a list to be able to input in to a JSON-file
    thisisjson_dict = json.loads(thisisjson)
    output[sheet] = thisisjson_dict
# Define file to write to and 'w' for write option -> json.dump() 
# defining the list to write from and file to write to
    with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(output, json_file)
```

Comment: Is there a way to collect names of all of the sheets and put it in a list?

Comment: if you don't enter a sheetname pandas will parse all of the sheets in the file and return a list of dataframes. You could just iterate over that list instead.